# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Angular Elasticsearch Kibana

Tags: angular, elasticsearch, cors, http-post, kibana-7

I have implemented an http post request (Angular) to a Kibana API endpoint but I am getting the following error.

**Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://XX.X.X.XXX:XXXX/internal/security/login' from origin 'http://YY.YY.Y.YYY:YYYY' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

This the Angular code

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
        'kbn-version': '7.6.2'});
    
        const body = {
            username: 'username1',
            password: 'password1'
        };

        return this.http.post('http://XX.X.X.XXX:XXXX/internal/security/login', body, { headers });
```

This is the `elasticsearch.yml`

```
cluster.name: Cluster
http.port: 9200
network.host: XX.X.X.XXX
node.data: true
node.ingest: false
node.master: true
node.max_local_storage_nodes: 1
node.name: Nodo_1
path.data: C:\Monitoring\elasticsearch\elasticsearch-7.6.2\data
path.logs: C:\Monitoring\elasticsearch\elasticsearch-7.6.2\logs
transport.tcp.port: 9300
http.cors.enabled: true
http.cors.allow-origin: "*"
http.cors.allow-methods: OPTIONS, HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
http.cors.allow-headers: kbn-version, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Engaged-Auth-Token, Authorization, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Content-Length
```

This is `kibana.yml`

```
server.port: 5601
server.host: "XX.X.X.XXX"
xpack.security.enabled: true
elasticsearch.hosts: ["http://XX.X.X.XXX:XXXX"]
elasticsearch.username: "username2"
elasticsearch.password: "password1"
```

Comment: Never access ES directly from frontend. More info in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65323171/8160318) of mine.

Answer (score -1):

This issue was happening because of CORS origin. you need to allow source origin under your cross-origin header property.

you can refer to this article: https://medium.com/@dtkatz/3-ways-to-fix-the-cors-error-and-how-access-control-allow-origin-works-d97d55946d9

I prefer handling at server side for this issue, instead of implementing something at client side